# Как размножить один и тот же stateless компонент, что бы у каждого был автономный state? Используя бибилиотеку recompose

Tags: reactjs

Вопрос к специалиста по React.js

есть stateless компонент

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {
  compose,
  withState,
  withHandlers,
} from 'recompose';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ColumnPresentation from './ColumnPresentation';
import { setPlayerStep, setWinner } from '../GameState';


export default compose(
  connect(
    state => ({
      playerStep: state.game.playerStep,
      winner: state.game.winner,
    }),
    dispatch => ({
      setPlayerStep: () => dispatch(setPlayerStep()),
      setWinner: winner => dispatch(setWinner(winner)),
    }),
  ),
  withState('count', 'setCount', 0),
  withState('arrayFiller', 'setArrayFiller', [...Array(6)]),
  withHandlers({
    incrementCount: props => () => {
      props.setCount(props.count + 1);
    },
  }),
)(ColumnPresentation);
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import Cell from '../../../components/Cell';


function columnPresentation({
  arrayFiller,
  incrementCount,
}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        onClick={incrementCount}
        style={{ flexDirection: 'column', display: 'inline-block' }}
        role="button"
        tabIndex={0}
      >
        <p>Hello</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


export default columnPresentation;
```

Как теперь этот компонент размножить:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ColumnPresentation from '../column/ColumnPresentationContainer';

function homePresentation() {
  return (
    <div style={styles.container}>
      <ColumnPresentation />
      <ColumnPresentation />
    </div>
  );
}

const styles = {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
};

export default homePresentation;
```

Что был каждого был свой state, независимый от других?  У меня при клике на один, почему то меняется state второго компонента

Comment: Сделайте контейнер

Comment: Не совсем понял? Так у меня есть вью и контейнер? самый первый блок кода?

Answer (score 0):

Stateless компоненты не имеют своего состояния - они принимают на вход параметры и отдают jsx для отображения.
**Они являются простой функцией.**

Если есть необходимость сохранять состояние у части приложения можно сделать следующее:

1. Создать полноценный компонент и хранить состояние в локальном state - что будет удобнее всего в данном случае. React-приложение состоит из множества компонентов хранящих свое состояние.
2. Вынести сохранение состояние в контейнер или компонент выше - обычно  или контейнер для страницы. Передавать в каждый stateless - компонент свою переменную для манипуляции.
3. Хранить состояние в одном из state-менеджеров: например Redux, Mobx

Comment: Я немного не правильно вопрос сформулировал. Тут речь идет конкретно о библиотеке recompose

Comment: И конкретно этот пример. Я знаю что есть Redux, речь не об этом